# How override request to file in .htaccess file Apache2?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

```
# Structure
- example.com/static
-- .htaccess
-- images
--- file.png
--- file_cache.png
-- photos
--- file.jpg
--- file_cache.jpg
```

I want rewrite this rule GET param from URI and return file.

For example:

http://example.com/static/images/file.png

*(- server will trying return file by link)*

> BUT!

When user declare GET param and value equal "type=cache".

Then by link

http://example.com/static/images/file.png?type=cache

server **RETURN** file

http://example.com/static/images/file_cache.png

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file `static/images/.htaccess` and use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^file\.(png|jpe?g)$ file_%1.$1? [L,NC]
```

Comment: Can you provide details here. With this rule what url did you use and what error you got

Comment: @Nick: "This is not work for me" isn't a very helpful report. What unexpected behaviour did you see?